# How to edit layers in layered PDF?

Tags: layers, mapinfo, pdf

I was wondering whether it is possible for a layered PDF created by MapInfo to hide the label of a layer in the layer list of the PDF, to prevent the user from altering the visibility of the layer, with the layer still being seen on the map?  I've heard you can right click the layer in the PDF document, and then select properties, but this seems to be disabled in my version of Adobe?

Comment: I google it and see if you can do this https://www.google.com/search?q=How+to+edit+layers+in+layered+PDF%3F&oq=How+to+edit+layers+in+layered+PDF%3F&aqs=chrome..69i57j69i60.391j0j8&sourceid=chrome&ie=UTF-8

Comment: You can edit layered PDF's in Adobe Illustrator, Adobe Reader DC will only be able to read the PDF not edit it.

Comment: I've had a look at the article recommended- looks promising?